# Apex callout using multipart/form . JPEG works, PDF does not?

Tags: apex, callout, httprequest, postman

I have been working through setting up a callout using POST, using a multipart/form-data content type via apex.  Currently just validating the request generation via a mock server hosted on postman.

My solution is based on Daniel Ballinger's, along with a number of other incremental improvements I've seen on here.

What I'm seeing is that when I send a JPEG, the mock server receives the request and I can see the binary in the body of the request.

However, when I send over a PDF, the server is getting the request but it doesn't register as having any request body.

I've confirmed that prior to decoding the string to a blob, there is definitely a request being formed. It *looks* right - the boundaries seem the same as the boundaries in the JPEG request, but Postman disagrees.

Is there something specific about PDFs that may be an obstacle to successfully sending in a multipart request?

Edit to add code that is constructing the body:

```
 Id cvId = params.get('fileId');
    ContentVersion cv = getContentVersion(cvId);
    
  
    String fileName = cv.Title;
    String mimeType = cv.FileType;
    Blob fileBlob = cv.VersionData;
    
    String formString = '';

    formString += MultiPartFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
    
    MultiPartFormBuilder.WriteFileResult result = MultiPartFormBuilder.WriteFile('file', fileName, mimeType, fileBlob);
    formString += result.Content;
    formString += MultiPartFormBuilder.WriteBoundary(result.EndingType);

   
    blob formBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(formString);

   
    return formBlob;
```

And code that is called by the above code:

```
public class MultipartFormBuilder {

/*This code and pattern heavily based upon and derived from solutions described by Dan Ballinger and Enrico Murro*/

private final static String Boundary = '1ff13444ed8140c7a32fc4e6451aa76d';  

public static String GetContentType() {
    return 'multipart/form-data; charset="UTF-8"; boundary="' + Boundary + '"';
}


private static String SafelyPad(
    String value,
    String valueCrLf64,
    String lineBreaks) {

    String valueCrLf = '';
    Blob valueCrLfBlob = null;

    while (valueCrLf64.endsWith('=')) {
        value += ' ';
        valueCrLf = value + lineBreaks;
        valueCrLfBlob = Blob.valueOf(valueCrLf);
        valueCrLf64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(valueCrLfBlob);
    }

    return valueCrLf64;
}


public static String WriteBoundary() {
    String value = '--' + Boundary + '\r\n';
    Blob valueBlob = Blob.valueOf(value);

    return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(valueBlob);
}

public static String WriteBoundary(
    EndingType ending) {
    String value = '';

    if (ending == EndingType.Cr) {
        value += '\n';
    } else if (ending == EndingType.None) {
        value += '\r\n';
    }

    value += '--' + Boundary + '--';

    Blob valueBlob = Blob.valueOf(value);

    return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(valueBlob);
}

public static WriteFileResult WriteFile(String key, String value, String mimeType, Blob fileBlob) {

    EndingType ending = EndingType.None;
    String contentDisposition = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + key + '"; filename="' + value + '"';
    String contentDispositionCrLf = contentDisposition + '\r\n';
    
    Blob contentDispositionCrLfBlob = Blob.valueOf(contentDispositionCrLf);
    
    String contentDispositionCrLf64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentDispositionCrlfBlob);
    
    String content = SafelyPad(contentDisposition, contentDispositionCrLf64, '\r\n');
    
    String contentType = 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType;
    String contentTypeCrLf = contentType + '\r\n\r\n';
    
    Blob contentTypeCrLfBlob = Blob.valueOf(contentTypeCrLf);
    
    String contentTypeCrLf64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentTypeCrLfBlob);

    content += SafelyPad(contentType, contentTypeCrLf64, '\r\n\r\n');

    String file64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(fileBlob);

    String file64ending = file64.substring(file64.length()-4,file64.length());


    if (file64ending.endsWith('==')) {
        file64ending = file64ending.substring(0,2) + '0K';
        file64 = file64.substring(0,file64.length()-4) + file64ending;
        ending = EndingType.CrLf;
    } else if (file64ending.endsWith('=')) {
        file64ending = file64ending.substring(0,3) + 'N';
        file64 = file64.substring(0,file64.length()-4) + file64ending;
        ending = EndingType.Cr;
    }

    content += file64;
    
    return new WriteFileResult(content, ending);
}


public static String WriteBodyParameter(
    String key,
    String value) {
    
    
    String contentDisposition = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + key + '"';
    String contentDispositionCrLf = contentDisposition + '\r\n\r\n';
    Blob contentDispositionCrLfBlob = Blob.valueOf(contentDispositionCrLf);
    String contentDispositionCrLf64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentDispositionCrLfBlob);
    String content = SafelyPad(contentDisposition, contentDispositionCrLf64, '\r\n\r\n');
    String valueCrLf = value + '\r\n';
    Blob valueCrLfBlob = Blob.valueOf(valueCrLf);
    String valueCrLf64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(valueCrLfBlob);

    content += SafelyPad(value, valueCrLf64, '\r\n');
        
    return content;
}


public class WriteFileResult {
    public final String Content { get; private set; }
    public final EndingType EndingType { get; private set; }

    public WriteFileResult(
        String content,
        EndingType ending) {
        this.Content = content;
        this.EndingType = ending;
    }
}


public enum EndingType {
    Cr,
    CrLf,
    None
}
```

}

Comment: At a basic level, no. Data is data. We'd need to see how your constructing your request in order to help you further.

Comment: I edited my original post to add the code for building the body of the request.